# Adreno-GSL and AdMob Crashes

Tags: android, admob

I was hoping someone could help me translate what this error message means so I can fixes my app crashes. An few hours of scouring Google etc has yielded no clues.

LogCat Output:

```
03-15 22:33:12.383: W/Adreno-GSL(31852): <gsl_ldd_control:393>: ioctl fd 55 code     0xc0140910 (IOCTL_KGSL_RINGBUFFER_ISSUEIBCMDS) failed: errno 71 Protocol error
03-15 22:33:12.383: W/Adreno-GSL(31852): <log_gpu_snapshot:308>: panel.gpuSnapshotPath is not set.not generating user snapshot
03-15 22:33:13.173: W/Adreno-GSL(31852): <gsl_ldd_control:393>: ioctl fd 55 code 0xc0140910 (IOCTL_KGSL_RINGBUFFER_ISSUEIBCMDS) failed: errno 35 Resource deadlock would occur
03-15 22:33:13.173: W/Adreno-GSL(31852): <log_gpu_snapshot:308>: panel.gpuSnapshotPath is not set.not generating user snapshot
03-15 22:33:13.173: W/Adreno-GSL(31852): <gsl_ldd_control:393>: ioctl fd 55 code 0xc0140910 (IOCTL_KGSL_RINGBUFFER_ISSUEIBCMDS) failed: errno 35 Resource deadlock would occur
03-15 22:33:13.173: W/Adreno-GSL(31852): <log_gpu_snapshot:308>: panel.gpuSnapshotPath is not set.not generating user snapshot
```

I have narrowed it down to my Ad Mobile code. If I put the code below in either the onCreate or onResume sections of my main activity it crashes with the above error (Samsung Galaxy S4). If added in after a delay there doesn't seem to be a problem.

```
    if (adView == null && GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()) ==  ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        adView = new AdView(this);
        if (adView != null){
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addBar);
            if (layout != null){
                layout.addView(adView);         
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB")
                .build();
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code below : 
Also use your app to different devices so you will be able to see what's the real problem

```
if (adView == null && GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()) ==  ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){


adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addBar);
layout.addView(adView); 
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```